# Connection reset on JDK 17 + Wildfly 26.1.3 Final

Tags: jboss, wildfly, java-11, java-17

I'm facing issue regrading connection reset when upgrade a legacy system from jdk11/Wildfly16.x to jdk17/Widlfy26.1.3 Final

I'm following this example to do a custom-login realm under elytron subsystem https://github.com/wildfly-security-incubator/elytron-examples/tree/main/custom-realm

Here're application log

```
Line 445026: 2023-03-16 22:56:44,053 FINE  [org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory] (default task-2) Secure session established
Line 445027: 2023-03-16 22:56:44,053 FINE  [org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory] (default task-2)  negotiated protocol: TLSv1.2
Line 445028: 2023-03-16 22:56:44,053 FINE  [org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory] (default task-2)  negotiated cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Line 445029: 2023-03-16 22:56:44,053 FINE  [org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory] (default task-2)  peer principal: CN=testapi.domain.com
Line 445030: 2023-03-16 22:56:44,053 FINE  [org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory] (default task-2)  peer alternative names: [testapi.domain.com]
Line 445031: 2023-03-16 22:56:44,054 FINE  [org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory] (default task-2)  issuer principal: CN=domain-CA, DC=domain, DC=com
Line 445032: 2023-03-16 22:56:44,054 FINE  [org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator] (default task-2) Connection established 10.69.11.186:64540<->10.1.9.26:8443
Line 445033: 2023-03-16 22:56:44,054 FINE  [org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultManagedHttpClientConnection] (default task-2) http-outgoing-1: set socket timeout to 120000
Line 445034: 2023-03-16 22:56:44,054 FINE  [org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec] (default task-2) Executing request POST /Api/Accounts/AccountDetails?ip=localhost&Version=1 HTTP/1.1
Line 445035: 2023-03-16 22:56:44,054 FINE  [org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec] (default task-2) Target auth state: UNCHALLENGED
Line 445036: 2023-03-16 22:56:44,054 FINE  [org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec] (default task-2) Proxy auth state: UNCHALLENGED
Line 445037: 2023-03-16 22:56:44,054 FINE  [org.apache.http.headers] (default task-2) http-outgoing-1 >> POST /Api/Accounts/AccountDetails?Ip=localhost&Version=1 HTTP/1.1
Line 445038: 2023-03-16 22:56:44,055 FINE  [org.apache.http.headers] (default task-2) http-outgoing-1 >> Content-Type: application/json
Line 445039: 2023-03-16 22:56:44,055 FINE  [org.apache.http.headers] (default task-2) http-outgoing-1 >> Content-Length: 9
Line 445040: 2023-03-16 22:56:44,055 FINE  [org.apache.http.headers] (default task-2) http-outgoing-1 >> Host: test-api.Line 445026: 2023-03-16 22:56:44,053 FINE  [org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory] (default task-2) Secure session established
Line 445027: 2023-03-16 22:56:44,053 FINE  [org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory] (default task-2)  negotiated protocol: TLSv1.2
Line 445028: 2023-03-16 22:56:44,053 FINE  [org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory] (default task-2)  negotiated cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Line 445029: 2023-03-16 22:56:44,053 FINE  [org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory] (default task-2)  peer principal: CN=testapi.domain.com
Line 445030: 2023-03-16 22:56:44,053 FINE  [org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory] (default task-2)  peer alternative names: [testapi.domain.com]
Line 445031: 2023-03-16 22:56:44,054 FINE  [org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory] (default task-2)  issuer principal: CN=domain-CA, DC=domain, DC=com
Line 445032: 2023-03-16 22:56:44,054 FINE  [org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator] (default task-2) Connection established 10.69.11.186:64540<->10.1.9.26:8443
Line 445033: 2023-03-16 22:56:44,054 FINE  [org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultManagedHttpClientConnection] (default task-2) http-outgoing-1: set socket timeout to 120000
Line 445034: 2023-03-16 22:56:44,054 FINE  [org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec] (default task-2) Executing request POST /Api/Accounts/AccountDetails?Ip=localhost&Version=1 HTTP/1.1
Line 445035: 2023-03-16 22:56:44,054 FINE  [org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec] (default task-2) Target auth state: UNCHALLENGED
Line 445036: 2023-03-16 22:56:44,054 FINE  [org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec] (default task-2) Proxy auth state: UNCHALLENGED
Line 445037: 2023-03-16 22:56:44,054 FINE  [org.apache.http.headers] (default task-2) http-outgoing-1 >> POST /Api/Accounts/AccountDetails?Ip=localhost&Version=1 HTTP/1.1
Line 445038: 2023-03-16 22:56:44,055 FINE  [org.apache.http.headers] (default task-2) http-outgoing-1 >> Content-Type: application/json
Line 445039: 2023-03-16 22:56:44,055 FINE  [org.apache.http.headers] (default task-2) http-outgoing-1 >> Content-Length: 9
Line 445040: 2023-03-16 22:56:44,055 FINE  [org.apache.http.headers] (default task-2) http-outgoing-1 >> Host: testapi.domain.com:8443
Line 445041: 2023-03-16 22:56:44,055 FINE  [org.apache.http.headers] (default task-2) http-outgoing-1 >> Connection: Keep-Alive
Line 445042: 2023-03-16 22:56:44,055 FINE  [org.apache.http.headers] (default task-2) http-outgoing-1 >> User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.13 (Java/17.0.5)
Line 445043: 2023-03-16 22:56:44,055 FINE  [org.apache.http.headers] (default task-2) http-outgoing-1 >> Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Line 445044: 2023-03-16 22:56:44,056 FINE  [org.apache.http.wire] (default task-2) http-outgoing-1 >> "POST /Api/Accounts/AccountDetails?Ip=localhost&Version=1 HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
Line 445045: 2023-03-16 22:56:44,056 FINE  [org.apache.http.wire] (default task-2) http-outgoing-1 >> "Content-Type: application/json[\r][\n]"
Line 445046: 2023-03-16 22:56:44,056 FINE  [org.apache.http.wire] (default task-2) http-outgoing-1 >> "Content-Length: 9[\r][\n]"
Line 445047: 2023-03-16 22:56:44,056 FINE  [org.apache.http.wire] (default task-2) http-outgoing-1 >> "Host: testapi.domain.com:8443[\r][\n]"
Line 445048: 2023-03-16 22:56:44,056 FINE  [org.apache.http.wire] (default task-2) http-outgoing-1 >> "Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]"
Line 445049: 2023-03-16 22:56:44,056 FINE  [org.apache.http.wire] (default task-2) http-outgoing-1 >> "User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.13 (Java/17.0.5)[\r][\n]"
Line 445050: 2023-03-16 22:56:44,056 FINE  [org.apache.http.wire] (default task-2) http-outgoing-1 >> "Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate[\r][\n]"
Line 445051: 2023-03-16 22:56:44,056 FINE  [org.apache.http.wire] (default task-2) http-outgoing-1 >> "[\r][\n]"
Line 445052: 2023-03-16 22:56:44,056 FINE  [org.apache.http.wire] (default task-2) http-outgoing-1 >> "[4342265]"
Line 445053: 2023-03-16 22:56:44,056 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2) javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|10 03|default task-2|2023-03-16 22:56:44.056 ICT|SSLSocketOutputRecord.java:334|WRITE: TLSv1.2 application_data, length = 382
Line 445054: 2023-03-16 22:56:44,057 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2) javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|10 03|default task-2|2023-03-16 22:56:44.057 ICT|SSLCipher.java:1773|Plaintext before ENCRYPTION (
Line 445055: 2023-03-16 22:56:44,057 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)   0000: 50 4F 53 54 20 2F 6A 4D   61 6E 61 67 65 72 53 65  POST /Api/Accou
Line 445058: 2023-03-16 22:56:44,057 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)   0030: 6E 74 73 2F 41 63 63 6F   75 6E 74 44 65 74 61 69  nts/AccountDetai
Line 445059: 2023-03-16 22:56:44,057 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)   0040: 6C 73 3F 58 4D 55 73 65   72 49 70 3D 6C 6F 63 61  ls?Ip=loca
Line 445060: 2023-03-16 22:56:44,057 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)   0050: 6C 68 6F 73 74 26 56 65   72 73 69 6F 6E 3D 31 26  lhost HTTP/
Line 445065: 2023-03-16 22:56:44,057 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)   00A0: 31 2E 31 0D 0A 43 6F 6E   74 65 6E 74 2D 54 79 70  1.1..Content-Typ
Line 445066: 2023-03-16 22:56:44,057 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)   00B0: 65 3A 20 61 70 70 6C 69   63 61 74 69 6F 6E 2F 6A  e: application/j
Line 445067: 2023-03-16 22:56:44,057 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)   00C0: 73 6F 6E 0D 0A 43 6F 6E   74 65 6E 74 2D 4C 65 6E  son..Content-Len
Line 445068: 2023-03-16 22:56:44,057 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)   00D0: 67 74 68 3A 20 39 0D 0A   48 6F 73 74 3A 20 74 65  gth: 9..Host: te
Line 445069: 2023-03-16 22:56:44,057 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)   00E0: 73 74 2D 6A 6D 61 6E 61   67 65 72 2D 61 70 69 2E  st-api.
Line 445070: 2023-03-16 22:56:44,057 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)   00F0: 74 72 61 64 69 6E 67 2D   70 6F 69 6E 74 2E 63 6F  domain.co
Line 445071: 2023-03-16 22:56:44,057 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)   0100: 6D 3A 38 34 34 33 0D 0A   43 6F 6E 6E 65 63 74 69  m:8443..Connecti
Line 445072: 2023-03-16 22:56:44,057 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)   0110: 6F 6E 3A 20 4B 65 65 70   2D 41 6C 69 76 65 0D 0A  on: Keep-Alive..
Line 445073: 2023-03-16 22:56:44,057 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)   0120: 55 73 65 72 2D 41 67 65   6E 74 3A 20 41 70 61 63  User-Agent: Apac
Line 445074: 2023-03-16 22:56:44,057 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)   0130: 68 65 2D 48 74 74 70 43   6C 69 65 6E 74 2F 34 2E  he-HttpClient/4.
Line 445075: 2023-03-16 22:56:44,057 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)   0140: 35 2E 31 33 20 28 4A 61   76 61 2F 31 37 2E 30 2E  5.13 (Java/17.0.
Line 445076: 2023-03-16 22:56:44,057 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)   0150: 35 29 0D 0A 41 63 63 65   70 74 2D 45 6E 63 6F 64  5)..Accept-Encod
Line 445077: 2023-03-16 22:56:44,057 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)   0160: 69 6E 67 3A 20 67 7A 69   70 2C 64 65 66 6C 61 74  ing: gzip,deflat
Line 445078: 2023-03-16 22:56:44,057 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)   0170: 65 0D 0A 0D 0A 5B 34 33   34 32 32 36 35 5D        e....[4342265]
Line 445079: 2023-03-16 22:56:44,057 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2) )
Line 445080: 2023-03-16 22:56:44,057 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2) javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|10 03|default task-2|2023-03-16 22:56:44.057 ICT|SSLSocketOutputRecord.java:349|Raw write (
Line 445081: 2023-03-16 22:56:44,057 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)   0000: 17 03 03 01 96 00 00 00   00 00 00 00 01 89 E4 4F  ...............O
Line 445082: 2023-03-16 22:56:44,057 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)   0010: 82 B7 C4 6E B2 F4 EF 6A   1E 3F 8E 20 DE 5E 3D 7D  ...n...j.?. .^=.
Line 445105: 2023-03-16 22:56:44,058 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)   0180: 8E 2C 84 EF DE 90 C2 35   50 7C D8 57 F8 20 BF 18  .,.....5P..W. ..
Line 445106: 2023-03-16 22:56:44,058 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)   0190: 0D 3E 42 15 3C FB 2D BE   D6 90 70                 .>B.<.-...p
Line 445107: 2023-03-16 22:56:44,058 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2) )
Line 717403: 2023-03-16 22:56:59,464 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2) javax.net.ssl|WARNING|10 03|default task-2|2023-03-16 22:56:59.463 ICT|SSLSocketImpl.java:1671|handling exception (
Line 717404: 2023-03-16 22:56:59,464 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2) "throwable" : {
Line 717405: 2023-03-16 22:56:59,464 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)   java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
Line 717406: 2023-03-16 22:56:59,464 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.implRead(NioSocketImpl.java:323)
Line 717407: 2023-03-16 22:56:59,464 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.read(NioSocketImpl.java:350)
Line 717408: 2023-03-16 22:56:59,464 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl$1.read(NioSocketImpl.java:803)
Line 717409: 2023-03-16 22:56:59,464 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at java.base/java.net.Socket$SocketInputStream.read(Socket.java:976)
Line 717410: 2023-03-16 22:56:59,464 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.read(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:478)
Line 717411: 2023-03-16 22:56:59,464 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.readHeader(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:472)
Line 717412: 2023-03-16 22:56:59,464 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.bytesInCompletePacket(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:70)
Line 717413: 2023-03-16 22:56:59,464 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readApplicationRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1460)
Line 717414: 2023-03-16 22:56:59,464 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl$AppInputStream.read(SSLSocketImpl.java:1064)-point.com:8443
Line 445041: 2023-03-16 22:56:44,055 FINE  [org.apache.http.headers] (default task-2) http-outgoing-1 >> Connection: Keep-Alive
Line 445042: 2023-03-16 22:56:44,055 FINE  [org.apache.http.headers] (default task-2) http-outgoing-1 >> User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.13 (Java/17.0.5)
Line 445043: 2023-03-16 22:56:44,055 FINE  [org.apache.http.headers] (default task-2) http-outgoing-1 >> Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Line 445044: 2023-03-16 22:56:44,056 FINE  [org.apache.http.wire] (default task-2) http-outgoing-1 >> "POST /Api/Accounts/AccountDetails?Ip=localhost&Version=1 HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
Line 445045: 2023-03-16 22:56:44,056 FINE  [org.apache.http.wire] (default task-2) http-outgoing-1 >> "Content-Type: application/json[\r][\n]"
Line 445046: 2023-03-16 22:56:44,056 FINE  [org.apache.http.wire] (default task-2) http-outgoing-1 >> "Content-Length: 9[\r][\n]"
Line 445047: 2023-03-16 22:56:44,056 FINE  [org.apache.http.wire] (default task-2) http-outgoing-1 >> "Host: testapi.domain.com:8443[\r][\n]"
Line 445048: 2023-03-16 22:56:44,056 FINE  [org.apache.http.wire] (default task-2) http-outgoing-1 >> "Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]"
Line 445049: 2023-03-16 22:56:44,056 FINE  [org.apache.http.wire] (default task-2) http-outgoing-1 >> "User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.13 (Java/17.0.5)[\r][\n]"
Line 445050: 2023-03-16 22:56:44,056 FINE  [org.apache.http.wire] (default task-2) http-outgoing-1 >> "Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate[\r][\n]"
Line 445051: 2023-03-16 22:56:44,056 FINE  [org.apache.http.wire] (default task-2) http-outgoing-1 >> "[\r][\n]"
Line 445052: 2023-03-16 22:56:44,056 FINE  [org.apache.http.wire] (default task-2) http-outgoing-1 >> "[4342265]"
Line 445053: 2023-03-16 22:56:44,056 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2) javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|10 03|default task-2|2023-03-16 22:56:44.056 ICT|SSLSocketOutputRecord.java:334|WRITE: TLSv1.2 application_data, length = 382
Line 445054: 2023-03-16 22:56:44,057 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2) javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|10 03|default task-2|2023-03-16 22:56:44.057 ICT|SSLCipher.java:1773|Plaintext before ENCRYPTION (
Line 445055: 2023-03-16 22:56:44,057 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)   0000: 50 4F 53 54 20 2F 6A 4D   61 6E 61 67 65 72 53 65  POST /Api/Accou
Line 445058: 2023-03-16 22:56:44,057 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)   0030: 6E 74 73 2F 41 63 63 6F   75 6E 74 44 65 74 61 69  nts/AccountDetai
Line 445059: 2023-03-16 22:56:44,057 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)   0040: 6C 73 3F 58 4D 55 73 65   72 49 70 3D 6C 6F 63 61  ls?Ip=loca
Line 445060: 2023-03-16 22:56:44,057 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)   0050: 6C 68 6F 73 74 26 56 65   72 73 69 6F 6E 3D 31 26  lhost&Ver HTTP/
Line 445065: 2023-03-16 22:56:44,057 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)   00A0: 31 2E 31 0D 0A 43 6F 6E   74 65 6E 74 2D 54 79 70  1.1..Content-Typ
Line 445066: 2023-03-16 22:56:44,057 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)   00B0: 65 3A 20 61 70 70 6C 69   63 61 74 69 6F 6E 2F 6A  e: application/j
Line 445067: 2023-03-16 22:56:44,057 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)   00C0: 73 6F 6E 0D 0A 43 6F 6E   74 65 6E 74 2D 4C 65 6E  son..Content-Len
Line 445068: 2023-03-16 22:56:44,057 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)   00D0: 67 74 68 3A 20 39 0D 0A   48 6F 73 74 3A 20 74 65  gth: 9..Host: te
Line 445069: 2023-03-16 22:56:44,057 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)   00E0: 73 74 2D 6A 6D 61 6E 61   67 65 72 2D 61 70 69 2E  st-api.
Line 445070: 2023-03-16 22:56:44,057 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)   00F0: 74 72 61 64 69 6E 67 2D   70 6F 69 6E 74 2E 63 6F  domain.co
Line 445071: 2023-03-16 22:56:44,057 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)   0100: 6D 3A 38 34 34 33 0D 0A   43 6F 6E 6E 65 63 74 69  m:8443..Connecti
Line 445072: 2023-03-16 22:56:44,057 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)   0110: 6F 6E 3A 20 4B 65 65 70   2D 41 6C 69 76 65 0D 0A  on: Keep-Alive..
Line 445073: 2023-03-16 22:56:44,057 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)   0120: 55 73 65 72 2D 41 67 65   6E 74 3A 20 41 70 61 63  User-Agent: Apac
Line 445074: 2023-03-16 22:56:44,057 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)   0130: 68 65 2D 48 74 74 70 43   6C 69 65 6E 74 2F 34 2E  he-HttpClient/4.
Line 445075: 2023-03-16 22:56:44,057 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)   0140: 35 2E 31 33 20 28 4A 61   76 61 2F 31 37 2E 30 2E  5.13 (Java/17.0.
Line 445076: 2023-03-16 22:56:44,057 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)   0150: 35 29 0D 0A 41 63 63 65   70 74 2D 45 6E 63 6F 64  5)..Accept-Encod
Line 445077: 2023-03-16 22:56:44,057 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)   0160: 69 6E 67 3A 20 67 7A 69   70 2C 64 65 66 6C 61 74  ing: gzip,deflat
Line 445078: 2023-03-16 22:56:44,057 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)   0170: 65 0D 0A 0D 0A 5B 34 33   34 32 32 36 35 5D        e....[4342265]
Line 445079: 2023-03-16 22:56:44,057 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2) )
Line 445080: 2023-03-16 22:56:44,057 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2) javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|10 03|default task-2|2023-03-16 22:56:44.057 ICT|SSLSocketOutputRecord.java:349|Raw write (
Line 445081: 2023-03-16 22:56:44,057 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)   0000: 17 03 03 01 96 00 00 00   00 00 00 00 01 89 E4 4F  ...............O
Line 445082: 2023-03-16 22:56:44,057 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)   0010: 82 B7 C4 6E B2 F4 EF 6A   1E 3F 8E 20 DE 5E 3D 7D  ...n...j.?. .^=.
Line 445083: 2023-03-16 22:56:44,057 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)   0020: F5 9F 53 58 CE 7D AD FE   F7 C7 CA DD 84 64 28 45  ..SX.........d(E
Line 445104: 2023-03-16 22:56:44,058 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)   0170: 76 AC 38 93 7D 73 B2 29   D4 D6 7A 5A 07 0D F0 93  v.8..s.)..zZ....
Line 445105: 2023-03-16 22:56:44,058 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)   0180: 8E 2C 84 EF DE 90 C2 35   50 7C D8 57 F8 20 BF 18  .,.....5P..W. ..
Line 445106: 2023-03-16 22:56:44,058 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)   0190: 0D 3E 42 15 3C FB 2D BE   D6 90 70                 .>B.<.-...p
Line 445107: 2023-03-16 22:56:44,058 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2) )
Line 717403: 2023-03-16 22:56:59,464 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2) javax.net.ssl|WARNING|10 03|default task-2|2023-03-16 22:56:59.463 ICT|SSLSocketImpl.java:1671|handling exception (
Line 717404: 2023-03-16 22:56:59,464 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2) "throwable" : {
Line 717405: 2023-03-16 22:56:59,464 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)   java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
Line 717406: 2023-03-16 22:56:59,464 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.implRead(NioSocketImpl.java:323)
Line 717407: 2023-03-16 22:56:59,464 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.read(NioSocketImpl.java:350)
Line 717408: 2023-03-16 22:56:59,464 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl$1.read(NioSocketImpl.java:803)
Line 717409: 2023-03-16 22:56:59,464 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at java.base/java.net.Socket$SocketInputStream.read(Socket.java:976)
Line 717410: 2023-03-16 22:56:59,464 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.read(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:478)
Line 717411: 2023-03-16 22:56:59,464 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.readHeader(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:472)
Line 717412: 2023-03-16 22:56:59,464 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.bytesInCompletePacket(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:70)
Line 717413: 2023-03-16 22:56:59,464 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readApplicationRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1460)
Line 717414: 2023-03-16 22:56:59,464 ERROR [stderr] (default task-2)    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl$AppInputStream.read(SSLSocketImpl.java:1064)
```

The issue might not related to Wildfly because I'm facing same issue with jdk15/wildfly16. (Note that jdk11/wildfly16 work well)

I also check the apache HttpClient (4.5.13) which already enable TLSv1.2 and TLSv1.3, setup keeAlive but no luck.

Thank you very much for take a look

Comment: Many of the quickstarts in the elytron-examples repo were updated to the WildFly 27 dependencies. Since you're using 26, try switching to the 1.x branch.

Comment: Do you mean that should upgrade to Wildfly 27 instead of 26.x?

Comment: I'd recommend upgrading to WildFly 27, but if you want to use WildFly 26, then you should use the `1.x` branch of the elytron-examples repo.